# Error in using Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm going to use **Google Map V2** in my application, so I'm following tutorials on the web like [**this**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/).

But when I use **fragment tag** in **XML** layout and run application, it jumped to **DEBUG** window(view) of eclipse.

I've checked my codes line by line, and first error appears when I use **fragment tag** in **XML** layout!

I've created a test application (as below) and got error again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I know that when I use **fragment tag** in my layout, I'll got error.

Could you please tell me what is wrong !

Comment: Pls add Logcat error file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following code in the application tag in manifest he missed that line in that example

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and replace the following in the layout file

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Tank you for hint... That's solution of my problem